# How to prove $\zeta'(0)/\zeta(0)=\log(2\pi)$?

Tags: calculus, riemann-zeta

How do I prove that $\zeta'(0)/\zeta(0)=\log(2\pi)$ ?

I can get $\zeta(0)=-\frac{1}{2}$, but I don't know how to calculate $\zeta'(0)=-\frac{1}{2}\log(2\pi)$ ? Can you help me ?

Here $\zeta(s)$ is Riemann zeta function:
$$\zeta(s):=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^s}. $$

Comment: Well by the above $\zeta(0)$ is undefined. The value of $\zeta(0)$ comes from Riemann's functional equation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you're interested to check $(38)$ [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunction.html).

The Wallis formula may also be written as 
$$\left(4^{\zeta{(0)}} \cdot e^{-\zeta'{(0)}}\right)^2=\frac{\pi}{2}$$
Chris.

Comment: Thank you very much ! It's helpful.

Comment: @DaoyiPeng: Welcome! Glad to hear that.

Answer (score 6):

Begin with
$$
\zeta(1-z) = 2 (2\pi)^{-z}\cos\frac{\pi z}{2} \Gamma(z)\;\zeta(z)
$$
then take logarithmic derivative.  Can you finish?

Comment: Could you explain more? I take logarithmic derivative but when letting $z \to 1$, it seems to diverge.